# tensorflow-addon not compatible with tensorflow 1.xx

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with code that is using tensorflow 1.14. Also they used tensorflow-addons, but as far as I understand tensorflow-addons that are available to install support tensorflow >= 2 only, because when I tried to install an older version of tf addons it says: 
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons==0.4.0 (from versions: 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.9.0, 0.9.1)"

And upgrading to tf2 would be very complicated, so I wanted to ask if there is any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons) it only works with TensorFlow 2+. So, there are two options for your situation.

- [Manual upgrade](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) your code to TensorFlow 2.0.
- Use an [automatic upgrade script](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade) to upgrade your code. It is an easier solution.

Also upgrading from 1.X to 2.2 can be more convenient. Because they keep core API the same with the 1.X versions as they said [here](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/03/recap-of-2020-tensorflow-dev-summit.html).